# Textarea protection against mysql injection- PHP

Tags: php, mysql, code-injection, html-entities

I have a textarea whose value will be inserted into a mysql database. To protect against a mysql injection, do I process the input through nl2br, mysql_real_escape_string, htmlentities, or a combination of 2 or all 3? In what order do I process the data?

Comment: Protecting against SQL injection is already well-covered all over the place.  You might also want to consider prepared statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nl2br` basically converts all `"\n"` to `"<br/>"`, so I don't see how it helps with sql injection (not mysql injection btw)

`mysql_real_escape_string` is usually used for this kind of thing.

`htmlentities` is used to prevent mishaps where users inject malicious `<script>` into your website if you allow user inputs. Note that it's usually an accepted practice to store string as is and only call `htmlentities` whenever you are outputting your string

You need to know what each of the above does and use them only when you need it, not combine them as they might break stuff even worse.

Another better and safer alternative for securing your database is to use `mysqli` http://sg.php.net/mysqli, it provides prepared statement to help you filter out your sql

Comment: This is misleading.  `mysqli` does not "automagically" filter out sql.  You have to use prepared statements specifically.  It would be very easy to construct a query with an injection in `mysqli` (or any DB wrapper used improperly).

Answer (score 3):

The **only** processing you need upon insertion is `mysql_real_escape_string`, but it is preferred that you use prepared statements perhaps with `PDO` or `MDB2`.

**Never** store encoded data in a database.  You should always store the raw data.  That is, don't use `nl2br` or `htmlentities` for storage.  You should, however, use it for *display* if the data is going to be inserted into the DOM (`nl2br` is purely visual, `htmlentities` will help protect against XSS).  Also note that `htmlspecialchars` may be preferred depending upon how you want to handle the display -- this should be sufficient for basic XSS protection.

Remember this mantra:

- Escape for storage
- Encode for display

Answer (score 0):

If you use prepared statements with PDO or mysqli then you simply bind the parameter. If using the old mysql extension then you should use `mysql_real_escape_string()`.